# super.initstate() not being called

Tags: flutter, dart

Im a new flutter developer and have just started using the initState(). However, it seems like it never gets called, I tried all fixes I found on here, but none of them works! Here is a simplified example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class example extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<example> {
    @override
    void Initstate() {
      super.initState();
      print('hello world');
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

The hello world never gets printed though!

Comment: First you have typo, it's `void initState()`. Then you have to call the `initState` before the `build` method.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Leonidis, it now works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initState is not supposed to be inside the build function. You can create the initState function by going to the line above @override before build(), type init, hit ctrl space and it will autocomplete. This would be the correct version:

```
class _State extends State<Example> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('hello world');
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```